# PHP List Directories Recursively Issue

Tags: php

I'm trying to list all PHP files in a specified directory and for it to recursively check all sub-directories until it finds no more, there could be numerous levels.

The function I have below works fine with the exception that it only recurses down one level.

I've spent hours trying to see where I'm going wrong, I'm calling the scanFiles() when it finds a new directory but this only seems to work one level down and stop, any help greatly appreciated.

### Updated:

```
function scanFiles($pParentDirectory)
{
    $vFileArray = scandir($pParentDirectory);
    $vDirectories = array();

    foreach ($vFileArray as $vKey => $vValue)
    {
        if (!in_array($vValue, array('.', '..')) && (strpos($vValue, '.php') || is_dir($vValue)))
        {
            if (!is_dir($vValue))
                $vDirectories[] = $vValue;
            else
            {
                $vDirectory = $vValue;
                $vSubFiles = scanFiles($vDirectory);
                foreach ($vSubFiles as $vKey => $vValue)
                        $vDirectories[] = $vDirectory.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$vValue;
            }
        }
    }

    return $vDirectories;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily like this:

```
// helper function
function getFiles(&$files, $dir) {
    $items = glob($dir . "/*");
    foreach ($items as $item) {
         if (is_dir($item)) {
            getFiles($files, $item);
        } else {
            if (end(explode('.', $item)) == 'php') {
                $files[] = basename($item);
            }
        }
    }
}

// usage
$files = array();
getFiles($files, "myDir");

// debug
var_dump($files);
```

**myDir** looks like this: *has php files in all dirs*

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

---

P.S. if you want the function to return the full path to the found `.php` files, remove the `basename()` from this line:

```
$files[] = basename($item);
```

This will then produce result like this:

[image]

hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't output the sub-directory, otherwise it's useless information as you can't tell where the files came from.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `$vDirectory` is just a folder name, so `scanDir` looks in the current folder for it, not the sub folder.

What you want to do is to pass in the path to the folder, not just the name. This should be as simple as changing your recursive call to `scanFiles($pParentDirectory . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $vDirectory)`

Answer (score -1):

Your main problem is functions like `scanDir` or `isDir` need the full file path to work.

If you pass the full file path to them, it should work correctly.